# Define global contants in velocity

Tags: java, velocity

`VM_global_library.vm` file is used for defining global macros that are available in all the templates.

I tried defining a variable in this file hoping it would become available in all my templates:

```
#set( $size_limit = 100)
```

However this doesn't work and `$size_limit` prints as a literal.

**How can I define a variable that is available in all my templates?** Is there a global version of `org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext`?

Comment: What is your configuration? Do you use a framework? VelocityTools ?

Comment: Yes I have velocity tools on classpath. Its a simple commandline application. I am using Velocity directly without integration with any enterprise framework.

Comment: Having VelocityTools in the classpath doen't mean you are **using** VelocityTools. Nevermind, I'll offer an answer for a direct use of Velocity.

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson Correct. What I meant was I'm open to solutions using VelocityTools as I have that in my project.

Comment: To produce its result, Velocity merges the VTL template against a Velocity Context object. To define a constant (or any other object) that would be accessible everywhere, you need to be able to put that constant in the context that will be used by Velocity. It's highly dependent on the framework you are using. It's not exactly that a solution to your problem would **use** VelocityTools, it's rather than your framework **does** or not use VelocityTools to integrate Velocity.